# Monkeyrunner doesnt find my module

Tags: python-module, monkeyrunner

I have installed `psutil` module.
It works well if run by the python interpreter but when I try to import the module in a monkeyrunner script,it gives

> No such module.

Is there any way through which i use psutil module in monkeyrunner?

Note-i am using the monkeyrunner with the android ics-x86 version

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? psutil will find cpu, memory, etc. info about your host not your device.

Comment: Given a process id,i want to check whether the process is running or not (on the device).Actually i am playing a video using startactivity function(monkeyrunner),and i want to know when the playback ends(rather handle that event in my monkeyrunner script)

Answer (score 0):

Try to name your script **something.py**. This way you have a python script where you can import the modules. When you run the script with monkeyrunner, some python modules are not recognized. Monkeyrunner does not equal python 100%. It does not have all the power and functionality.

Comment: so you mean there is no way using which i can import other modules not supported by monkeyrunner?                                 Because there is a way using which you can install other python modules in jython.                                                 See this link- http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/appendixA.html#setuptools                                      Since monkeyrunner uses jython can anything like that cant be done with monkeyrunner?